# problem in admin_path module with my custom content type paths

Tags: 7, nodes, modal-dialogs

I have created a content type "Test".

The content which I created of type "Test" have the paths like this "test/content1, test/content2 etc. means test/*".

So I entered the path "test/*" in the administrative pages.

But when I try to open any content of type "Test", First the url becomes like this "#overlay=test/content1" and then it redirects to "test/content1" and does not appear in overlay.

I tried some other paths of the contents of some other types and they are working fine in overlay.

So what is the problem with my custom content type? Any one who have some idea about t his?

Comment: Or is there any module which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Check out overlay_paths module. Should solve your problem. Sounds like admin_paths() isn't accepting up your url aliases. http://drupal.org/project/issues/overlay_paths.